# EFCore Best way to attach "calculated properties"

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Let's assume I have a table `Mail` and a table `Mail.Read` where a relation between Mails and Users having read the Mail is stored.

Now my Mail-Entity has an unbound property `DateTime? dateRead`, is there any possibility to somehow join this property, keeping an `IQueryable<Mail>`?

```
from m in dbContext.Mails
from mr in dbContext.MailsRead.Where(mr => mr.MailId = m.Id && mr.UserId == UserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Mail = m, Seen = (DateTime?)mr.DateCreated }
```

works but gives me a new type, so the result can't be passed in an `IQueryable<Mail>`. I'd like to somehow set the unbound property keeping a pure queryable.

For example

```
(from m in dbContext.Mails
from mr in dbContext.MailsRead.Where(mr => mr.MailId = m.Id && mr.UserId == UserId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Mail = m, Seen = (DateTime?)mr.DateCreated })
.Select(m => { m.DateSeen = m.Seen; return m.Mail; });
```

Sets the property while still being an IQueryable. Since EFCore cannot work with this query, filters (e.g. `.Where()`) are no longer possible after this solution.

Comment: Don't use JOINs (this is an attempt at a LEFT JOIN). Use proper relations instead. You shouldn't have to write anything more than `from m in dbConext.Mails from mr in m.Read where mr.UserId=UserId ....`. The JOIN will be created by EF from the relation

Comment: It is good way. Just create additional class `MailWithInfo` and pass to other functions `IQueryable<MailWithInfo>`

Comment: EF doesn't have formula properties like NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If the entities use proper relations and the `MailRead` entities appear as eg a `List<MailRead> MailsRead` property in `Mail`:

```
class Mail
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    ...
    public List<MailRead> MailsRead {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

You can write just :

```
var mails=dbContext.Mails.Inculde(m=>m.MailsRead
                                      .Where(mr=>mr.UserID == UserID);
```

[Filtered Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) were first introduced in EF Core 5.

If the entities don't have relations, they should. EF Core is an ORM. A DbContext isn't a model of the database, entities aren't tables and LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. As the name says, EF Core Maps Objects to Relational types. It's meant to allow the application to work with objects and map any operations to SQL.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, but the initial is simplified as far as possible. Actually it is a pretty generic database where a cannot use easy relations and the property "dateRead" must be part of the `class Mail` and may not be a relation property. Otherwise your answer would be quite good!

Comment: @tris as I already explained, EF Core isn't a model of the database or a replacement for SQL. There's no "generic" DbContext. The classes themselves are generic, but concrete instances contain entities and relations. If you don't want that you shouldn't be using EF Core. You could use eg raw SQL with Dapper to map results. Although what you ask, getting back an `IQueryable<>`, *requires* concrete types and relations.

Comment: @tris besides, that's what you asked. Post the *actual* query and describe the *actual* problem. In any case using EF Core as if it was SQL is a problem itself.

Comment: I adopted the question a bit. I'm want to know if EFCore serves a native way to use some kind of properties representing a query result. If not, I could / would use a table valued function for this.